# How to find the row for some column variable in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

For example in a big database I know value of the item in column then how will i get the corresponding index and column

Answer (score 0):

```
   col2 col3
id      
1   3   8
2   4   3
3   5   9
```

code:

```
df[df.isin([3])].stack().index.tolist()
```

result: (row_index,column_name)

```
[(1, 'col2'), (2, 'col3')]
```